# Linux console application development

Tags: linux, console

We need to develop a console application for Linux (Centos 6.x) similar to [what you see when VMware ESXi first boots](http://www.virtualizationadmin.com/img/upl/image0061217851729920.jpg). This console app will be used to initially configure Linux as a virtual appliance when the system first boots (prior to entering the Linux desktop console).

It's been years (decades, actually) since I did any console programming in Unix, which used to use the old "curses" library... I'm sure technology has advanced markedly since then and there must be many better options.

My question is:  What are the language options for developing a nice console UI today?  TCL?  Python?  Other?

Thanks
Rick

Answer (score 0):

You can use Python and Urwid: http://excess.org/urwid/